# Windows 7 Network dies after sleep mode

Tags: windows-7, networking, sleep

I have a windows 7 machine and everytime it comes back from sleep mode the network connection has been lost and needs reconnecting.

I have checked the power settings for my network card and it is set to never turn off.

Does anyone have any suggestions.

Comment: Is it a permanent connection which may receive data while the computer is in sleep mode? Because that would cause the other end of the connection not to get a timely reply and reset the connection. Your computer would only notice the reset after it returns from sleep, but the actual disconnect/reset could have happened long before that. - Setting the network card to never power off is not enough if the computer (not the NIC) has to parse the packet and reply to it (e.g. reply with a TCP *ack*).

Comment: What is the NIC manufacturer and model?

Comment: This is the wired connection?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to "Allow Computer to turn this device off to save power", instinct says to uncheck it, but this is rather confusing, because it then disables the 2nd option which is "Allow this device to wake the computer". So I would check them both, I've gotten wake on lan to work, I've only turned off power management when it really interfered, for example my usb ports would randomly shut off.

[image]

Comment: I've already checked and this is unticked, so the computer shouldn't be turning the network card off.

Comment: @FunkySi I kind of figured that's what you were referring to, but have you tried leaving it checked and also checking allow this device to wake the computer?

Comment: The Windows frontend settings UI is not reliable (think of it as being taken as "suggestions" rather than "instructions"), and the Power Settings are particularly so.  There is a `cmd` method (I'm sure a `ps` one exists as well) to set each peripheral's power state behaviors, you'll likely need to go that route, or if it's defaulting to a different power plan that you select every time, there's a group policy fix for that issue.