# Win 10 desktop loses wifi network connection frequently, especially when waking from sleep

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, sleep, brave

My Windows 10 desktop computer loses its wifi connection during sleep, which is acceptable to me, but then upon waking, it takes too long to reconnect. Sometimes it doesn't even connect automatically, and I need to manually choose (in the wifi settings) to connect to my home network again. See ¹.

Also odd: sometimes upon waking, the wifi icon indicates that there *is* a network connection temporarily, but then it loses network connection temporarily a couple of seconds after waking.

I've had this computer for many years, and I think this problem has only happened within the past ~6 months.

I've even upgraded my USB wifi dongle to a new one, and the problem still happens. And yes, the drivers are up-to-date.

These old questions seemed relevant, but I haven't found the answer yet:

- [Windows 10 no network connection after boot or sleep](https://superuser.com/q/1590675/74576)
- [Windows 7 Network dies after sleep mode](https://superuser.com/q/545500/74576)
- [Windows 10 WiFi connection after sleep](https://superuser.com/q/1135974/74576)
- [After putting Windows 10 laptop to sleep, wifi disconnects and cannot reconnect to any networks](https://superuser.com/q/1619989/74576)
- [Windows 10 networking on one adapter lost after sleep](https://superuser.com/q/1598994/74576)

P.S. `winver` shows I have Windows 10 Version 2004 (OS Build 19041.1083). My new wifi USB dongle is EDUP AC1300M wifi driver EP-AC1686 Driver (8812BU Chipset).

---

UPDATE:

Even https://superuser.com/a/982020/74576 (un-ticked "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power", in the "Power Management" tab of the wireless network adapter properties) did not fix the problem.

¹ Also, here is a screenshot of how upon waking I'm forced to click "Connect" even though "Connect automatically" had already been checked (but obviously isn't working).

[image: wifi status screenshot]

---

Update 2:

See [Windows 10 WiFi connection after sleep](https://superuser.com/questions/1135974/windows-10-wifi-connection-after-sleep?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment2610237_1135983) I wonder if my Brave browser is somehow the problem. I *nearly always* have Brave windows open, so if Brave is somehow able to disconnect my wifi temporarily upon Windows waking up (which doesn't make sense to me), then it would be Brave's fault.

---

Update 3:

It's not Brave's fault. "Connect automatically" still doesn't work (upon waking from sleep) even when I'd fully exited Brave prior to sleep.

Comment: @Moab Thanks but, as I mentioned, the drivers are already updated.

Comment: This has been a known issue for years, but I'm unsure what the cause is or whether it's ever been addressed by Microsoft. The most efficient way I've found to fix it is to manually disconnect from the network via the taskbar's network icon, then immediately reconnect once it's registers as disconnected.

Comment: @JW0914 Thanks for your response. Those extra steps so many times per day are driving me crazy. It didn't use to be like this.

Comment: As a Workaround, on a desktop PC used for work I'd just go into power settings and set Sleep to "never" as well as Hibernate to "never"  - or set it to sth like "after 2 hours".

Comment: @1NN I appreciate the flexible thinking. :-) But I'd personally prefer an actual solution.

Comment: Run as Administrator the command: `net stop WlanSvc && net start WlanSvc`. If this fixes the problem, it could be automated to run on wake from sleep.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks for your idea. I appreciate the flexible thinking, but I'm wary of hacks / workarounds that don't understand the root cause.

Comment: Try it - if it works then this is an indication. Perhaps only an indication of a bug in the network driver, but it's useful.

Comment: @harrymc I've run the command in the prompt as admin, and yes it does seem to disconnect and reconnect wifi. I don't know whether this tells us anything though. It doesn't seem surprising.

Answer (score 4):

**Method 1 : Power Options - Network connectivity in Standby**

- Run `regedit`
- Navigate to
  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9`
- Set the value of `Attributes` to `2`
- Close `regedit`
- Open *Start > Power Options*, where you should now have the option for
  "Network connectivity in Standby"
- Enable both "On battery" and "Plugged in"
- Reboot might be required.

[image]

**Method 2 : Group Policy Editor**

- Run `gpedit.msc`
- Navigate to
  *Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > System >
  Power Management > Sleep Settings*
- Enable
  "Allow network connectivity during connected-standby (on battery)"
  and
  "Allow network connectivity during connected-standby (plugged in)"
- Reboot might be required.

**Method 3 : Using powercfg**

This is essentially the same as the previous method.

- Run Command Prompt (CMD) as Administrator
- For Battery On Option enter:

  ```
  powercfg /setdcvalueindex scheme_current sub_none F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9 1
  ```
- For Plugged In enter:

  ```
  powercfg /setacvalueindex scheme_current sub_none F15576E8-98B7-4186-B944-EAFA664402D9 1
  ```
- Reboot might be required.

**Method 4 : Reconnect on wake**

This method is to be used when no other solution is found.
On wake it runs a command for restarting the Windows service that
is supposed to redo the connection (but doesn't).

- Create a `.bat` file containing:

  ```
  net stop WlanSvc && net start WlanSvc
  ```
- Run *Start > Task Scheduler*
- Click on "Create a Task"
- Enter suitable values in the "General"
- In the "Triggers" tab, choose "New"
- In the new panel choose "On an event" from the top drop-down menu
- Choose "Custom" under Settings
- Click "New Event Filter" and use the following:

  Event Level: Information
  Log Name: System
  Source: Power-Troubleshooter
  Event ID: 1
- Click OK
- In the Actions tab, choose the above `.bat` file
- In the Conditions tab, uncheck
  "Start the task only if the computer is on AC power"
- Click OK.

Comment: Thanks for this big answer! I've done the steps from Method 2, including the reboot. I noticed the "wifi disconnected" icon briefly in the system tray upon login after boot, which isn't a good sign, but I'll report back later with how it goes.

Comment: Yeah, within minutes, my network cut out, and I hadn't even put my Windows to sleep. Given that this has been happening with multiple USB wifi devices, it's unlikely to be the fault of the wifi device. But I wonder if it's some other intermittent hardware issue (such as the motherboard).  That feels unlikely too since I've noticed no other symptoms. But this problem is *so bizarre*! I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: I also did Method 1 just now, changing Attributes from 1 to 2. I haven't rebooted yet. So far, I see the new "tree" of Balanced > "Networking connectivity in Standby" > Setting: Enable. I.e. mine isn't split into "On battery" and "Plugged in", perhaps because it's a desktop. And currently Enable is grayed out and not editable.

Comment: This seems a problem of Windows. To verify that your Windows in as good a shape as possible: (1) [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html), (2) [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html), and finally (3) [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). If all this doesn't help, then this is just how Windows works today, and for me only Method 4 is left (unless someone comes up with something else).

Comment: Thanks! I did (2), which said `Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.`. (Note to self: I saved the output to \diagnosis\2022-01-05_wifi_connection\) I worry that steps (1) and (3) are too risky since they could end up making unknown changes to my system, then requiring me to figure even more out. Thanks for these tips.  That the file repairs help.

Comment: Ok I just tried `Method 4 : Reconnect on wake` too and unfortunately wifi cut out briefly multiple times within minutes of waking, including while I was trying to submit this comment.

Comment: Do you mean that that the computer goes to sleep while you're working?

Comment: No, I mean what has been happening recently (which this post is about) is that when I come back into my office and wake up my PC, the wifi is disconnected (even though "Connect automatically" is enabled) and then the icon changes briefly to show that it's connected and then it flickers back to disconnected for 30-90 seconds and then connects again. *Sometimes* I need to click Connect to get it to connect again. Usually I don't. Then sometimes later the wifi disconnects itself again for a moment. I own 2 USB wifi dongles (1 new), and it happens regardless of which one is plugged in.

Comment: Method 4 should have been failsafe. I think we're reaching the stage where the conclusion is a corruption in Windows. Run [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) followed by [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html). Were any errors found?

Comment: Ok. `Repair-WindowsImage -Online`, `Repair-WindowsImage -Online -ScanHealth`, and `Repair-WindowsImage -Online -RestoreHealth` each say 
Online           : True
ImageHealthState : Healthy
RestartNeeded    : False
`sfc /scannow` says "Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations." I really do appreciate your ideas though, @harrymc!

Comment: Problem is that I'm running out of ideas. Last ideas: (1) Add for Method 4 a delay of 30 seconds after wake, (2) This is quite heavy and the last resort: [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html). This is equivalent to a major Windows upgrade, so take the appropriate backups.

Comment: Thanks. Although I do subscribe to Backblaze, I never like to rely on backups (I try to avoid risky steps). If I'm going to do something like that, it leads me to consider trying to [force-enable a Win 11 upgrade](https://www.hellpc.net/how-to-bypass-tpm-and-cpu-requirements-windows-11-upgrade-unsupported-pc/) instead (my processor is Intel Core i7-6700k, which Microsoft absurdly isn't supporting, and I currently have no TPM 2.0 module). I wonder what in the world caused this huge wifi headache; this is so frustrating and mysterious. Thanks.

Comment: I don't recommend a forced upgrade to Windows 11. We're getting errors on our site that indicate it's not yet stable, besides the fact that it's unknown how well it will work on an unsupported platform.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just found a cool, really long HTML report generated via `netsh wlan show wlanreport` that shows 17 errors in the past 3 days. Says "Disconnect Reasons: The network is disconnected by the driver. (6), The driver disconnected while associating. (5), [etc...]" I'm having trouble understanding how to read it or what to do though. I'm tempted to buy and try a 3rd USB wifi card since I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: EventId 4003
2022-01-07T08:08:15
[‒]WLAN AutoConfig detected limited connectivity, attempting automatic recovery.
Recovery Type: 4
Error Code: 0x0
Trigger Reason: 7
IP Family: 0

Then when I look in Windows Event Viewer, I see many events with EventId 4003. This seems to be happening frequently even though my router signal is strong.

Comment: The problem seem to be in either the network adapter, the network driver or the router. Windows itself seems to be OK. You could try to refresh the driver by deleting the network device in Device Manager and rebooting. The router can be factory-reset or the firmware updated. A third adapter might be an overkill, but coincidences can happen. I hope that the problem is not with the ISP.

Comment: I doubt the ISP is the problem since other devices in my house haven't had problems. I've already uninstalled the driver and installed the latest from the mfg's (EDUP) website, which hasn't helped. I don't want to reinstall Windows. I'll see if I can reset the AT&T Arris BGW210-700 gateway, which is definitely not great hardware. Thanks.

Comment: I awarded a bunch of points even though I still don't know how to fix my problem (because I really appreciated your continued effort). :-)

Comment: I appreciate it. From my ideas, [Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) is one you haven't done yet. This isn't a reset of Windows - it's exactly the same as doing a major Windows upgrade, although it'll only "upgrade" your version to itself. Take backups appropriately.

Comment: Saved my life again

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I missed this being menitioned.

1. Open **Device Manager** and locate your wifi adapter.
2. Change the view to `Devices by Connection`.

   [image]
3. Check the `Proerties` dialog > `Power Management` tab for the adapter *and all parent devices* and uncheck `Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power`.

   [image]

Comment: 2 bits are interesting about this suggestion: 1) I'd already unchecked that box for this network adapter in recent days, but somehow *it got enabled again* (I wonder what re-checked its box.) 2) I hadn't thought about this view and unchecking for all parent devices.  We'll see over the next day or so. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome. Interesting that it was re-enabled; probalby tied to Power Management and c ompliance with whatever standards exist for EnergyStar, etc. `Devices by connection` is a handy view when troubleshooting unknown/disabled devices. Sometimes deleting the parent device of an unknown device will cause it to be re-detected and identified.

Comment: Also, you said sometimes the network appears to be connnected when waking up but is then lost. Unless you see evidence of actual network activity, I think you're probably seeing a view/state that was cached when going to sleep. The network is probably already disconnected on wake, it's just the Notification Area icon hasn't refreshed to reflect the currennt state.

Comment: Unfortunately these steps have not solved the problem for me. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It might be an issue with your wireless card, I had the same issue & bought this gadget for around 2$ and still working good. No more issues, it has better strength than the laptop one as well

[image]

Comment: I've tried multiple USB wireless dongles, and the problem happens with both.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check for malware using a trusted antivirus software.
2. Boot in Safe Mode. If Wi-Fi works in Safe Mode it's a problem with something you installed.
3. Update Windows.

Comment: I booted into [Safe Mode with Networking](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234), but apparently that only supports ethernet rather than the wifi driver, which was disabled.